# how to fix mismatched arity deprecation in RSpec 2.99.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, deprecation-warning

I am migrating from RSpec 2 to RSpec 3. While trying to remove all deprecations with Rspec 2.99.2, I have resolved all other deprecations. Except,

```
stubbing implementations with mismatched arity is deprecated. Called from /path/to/file.rb:60:in `block in deliver_grouped_system_event_notification'.
stubbing implementations with mismatched arity is deprecated. Called from /path/to/file.rb:26:in `send_notification'.
```

This is the file:60

```
 supports.each{ |support, system_events| Mailer.grouped_system_event_email(support, system_events).deliver_now }
```

This is the original method

```
def grouped_system_event_email(support, system_events)
  @recipients   = support.email
  @subject      = "[ #{ENVIRONMENT_NAME} Grouped System Event List] #{system_events.first.customer.symbol}"
  @system_events = system_events

  mail(to: @recipients, subject: @subject)
```

end

This is where it is stubbed

```
      Mailer.stub :grouped_system_event_email, &@email_spy
```

The lambda &@email_spy

```
 @email_spy = lambda do
  @email_sent = true
  stub = OpenStruct.new
  stub.stub :deliver_now
  stub
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran 'transpec' which converts RSpec 2 syntaxes to RSpec 3.

```
gem install transpec
myproject$ transpec
```

this actually gave more insights about the error.

```
 from: Klass.any_instance.stub(:message)
 to: allow_any_instance_of(Klass).to receive(:message)
```

After running transpec, the following was the transition

From

```
Mailer.stub :system_event_email, &@email_spy
```

To

```
allow(Mailer).to receive :system_event_email, &@email_spy
```